# How to convert from DataFrame row to datetime format?

Tags: python, pandas, date-format

I have the following df

```
0    05/08/2013 16:04:02:155
1    05/08/2013 16:04:02:170
2    05/08/2013 16:04:02:217
3    10/07/2013 16:40:51:787
4    07/24/2014 09:50:30:228
Name: ctimestamp, dtype: object
```

I need convert to date time

`df['ctimestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ctimestamp'])`

But I have this error

```
raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 05/08/2013 16: 04: 02: 155
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: @PedroLobito actually don't have spaces

Comment: You have an extra `:`. eg. `16:04:02:155` you need to change it to `16:04:02.155`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What do/don’t you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the date format for your string because it is not in the most popular format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['ctimestamp'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f")
```

This will work.